# Creating a specific pattern with two-dimensional array in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, multidimensional-array

So my problem is that I would want to change two-dimensional int array's values to 1 so that the array would look like this

0 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 0
0 0 1 0 0

I have a parameter "size" in my function that equals to the array size. So I would want to create this pattern regardless of the array size

Example with size equal to 9:

0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0

Oh and size is always an odd integer obviously so that it is possible to create this tilted square "shape". Please Help!!

Comment: What did you try? Seems like you have more than just scala in your tags, but no code to show what you tried.

Comment: If you program in one language, please don't spam unrelated language tags. Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Well I have no code because I don't even know how to approach this problem. That's why I'm asking here

Comment: Hi @MatiasBerglund, welcome to **StackOverflow**, this isn't a place for asking _"this is my problem, please give me some code"_ neither for asking "how can I do this, without giving me the code". You may get help in other sites like maybe the [scala gitter channel](https://gitter.im/scala/scala), but even there people will be more willing to help if you prove that you already tried something - solving the problem is **your task!**, we can help you with code specific problems.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
  def createDiamond(size: Int) = {
    require(size % 2 != 0, "size must be odd")
    def innerIterator(limit: Int) = {
      (0 until size).map{ column =>
        if(column > ((size / 2) + limit) || column < ((size / 2) - limit)) "0"
        else "1"
      }.mkString(" ") + "\n"
    }

    val str = (0 until size).map{ row => if(row <= size / 2) innerIterator(row) else innerIterator(size - row - 1)}.mkString("")
    println(str)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def createFilter(size: Int, value: Int) :Array[Array[Int]] = {
   val middle = size / 2
   if (size % 2 == 1) {
     Array.fill(size, size)(value) 
   } else {
     Array.tabulate(size + 1, size + 1)((x, y) => 
     if (abs(middle - x) + abs(middle - y) 
     <= middle) value else 0)
   }
 }
```